# How to create unique list of codes from multiple files in multiple subfolders in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a folder structure in data lake like this:

```
folder1/subfolderA/parquet files
folder1/subfolderB/parquet files
folder1/subfolderC/parquet files
folder1/subfolderD/parquet files
etc.
```

All the parquet files have the same schema, and all the parquet files have, amongst other fields, a code field, let's call it code_XX.
Now I want from all parquet files in all folders the distinct value of code_XX.
So if code_XX, value 'A345' resides multiple times in the parquet files in subfolderA and subfolderC, I only want it once.
Output must be a Parquet file with all unique codes.

Is this doable in Azure Data Factory, and how?
If not, can it be done in Databricks?

Comment: Maybe Azure Data Explorer will fit your needs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/. It can query your data lake files and retrieve all unique code_XX values using one query. No need to ingest all files (with all other columns) to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below.

Set source folder path to recursively look for all parquet files and choose a column to store the file names.

[image]

As it seems you only need file names in output parquet file, use `select` to have only that column forward.

[image]

Use expression in derived column to get the file names from path string.

```
distinct(array(right(fileNames,locate('/',reverse(fileNames))-1)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thnx for taking the time to answer. I try to get a line break, but don't know how to force that in stackoverflow ;(
But I hope it is clear that my root folder is folder1 and beneath folder1 I have subfoldersA/B/C/D.
All those subfolders have parquet files of the same structure and the CONTENT of these files have, amongst other attributes, code_XX. I want the distinct values of code_XX.
It looks like you are checking the filenames, not the content of the files. Am I right?

Comment: New lines are not allowed in the comment section: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments

Comment: @Ron, yea I got it as that. But I see that you have it solved, cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SQL, it can be done with two copy activities, no need for data flows.

1. **Copy Activity 1 (Parquet to SQL):** Ingest all files into a staging table.
2. **Copy Activity 2 (SQL to Parquet):** Select DISTINCT `code_XX` from the staging table.

**NOTE:**

1. Use Mapping to only extract the column you need.
2. Use a wildcard file path with the recursive option enabled to copy all files from subfolders. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#blob-storage-as-a-source-type

Comment: Thnx Nicolas, I think that is an option as well.
Also Mark Kromer send a solution:
Add a data flow to your pipeline. In the data flow, add a single Parquet source that reads each Parquet file from folder1 using a wildcard like folders1/**/*.parquet. 
At this point, ADF will give you a single data frame with all of the rows from each Parquet file. 
You can then use Assert or Aggregate transformations to look for unique values in that new single federated dataset.

Thnx all

Comment: @Ron no worries. If you do not have SQL then Data Flow is your best option, if you do have SQL you might find this is faster and cheaper to run.

Comment: @Ron, can you post your comment with some details how you solved it, as an answer ?

Comment: Hi, for now I am on holiday. Once coming back in the office I have to see if and how they solved. Ley you know then